# jQuery print value from ajax get

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have code:

```
var availableSlots = "";
$.get( '', { availableSlots: userName }, function(a) { 
   availableSlots = a;
});
alert(availableSlots);
```

But alert outputs null, yes, when I put alert inside get, then everything works ok, but I need to use this value in another function. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make sure the **asynchronous** event already returned a value before you use the value of the global variable `availableSlots`.